# youtube api get all videos from channel in a single call

Tags: javascript, json, rest, youtube-api

youtube api get all videos from channel , I am trying to get channel's videos using the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY} 
&channelId=UC4of8xqL-SpDvTdOrRzS4sw
&part=snippet,id&order=date
&maxResults=111
```

It only returns 50 results even though I am passing 111 for the `maxResults` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a value of maxResults > 50.  You can set max results to < 50 to limit it more but 50 is the max.

When you get a response, you should see a `nextPageToken` in the response.  You will need to invoke the API again, providing this token to get the next set of results if you want to list everything.  If you want all results, keep paging and building a list of results until the `nextPageToken` is missing/null.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY} 
&channelId=UC4of8xqL-SpDvTdOrRzS4sw
&part=snippet,id&order=date
&maxResults=111 
&pageToken=abc123
```

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list